# can a button lose its onclick listener if its repeatedly hidden and shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I have two buttons say "Button A" and "Button B" initially both of which are visible. Clicking  Button B sends a ajax request which brings data and then sets `display:none` on 'button A' . Again on clicking Button B it brings data but this time sets `display:block` on 'button A' . 
After repeatedly doing the above for  some 10-15 times , button A stops responding and its  onClick function is not even called .
It happens only in chrome , not in IE.

Setting `visibility :visible` and `visiblity:hidden` solves the issues but using display property is the requirement.

Is there any solution for the above issue .

Comment: please add your source code

Comment: why is the requirements using `display`? What is that? An assignment? Don't expect that someone solve it for you

Comment: can you add UI sketch? I can't imagine what your UI looks like. I don't think 'display: block' is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either like this:

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<!-- End Overlay -->
<button id="toggler">Apply Overlay</button>
<div id="sB">

<button id="closeit">Close Overlay</button>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/VevpwM

See, the second button is not shown at all times.

Or, if you can use Jquery, you can bind the eventHandler to elements which do not exists yet like this:

```
$(document).on("click","your button",function(){ your function block});
```

This will do, I do not know how to do this in vanilla JS, if somebody could explain this, I would appreciate this very much.

Regards